# Is there any xarray function to extract similer time as other file?

Tags: python, timestamp, where-clause, python-xarray

Here `ds1` (jan) and `ds2` (feb) have total number of samples are 100 (1900 year - 2000 year)

```
ds1 = xr.open_dataset('data1_jan.nc',decode_times=False) #.load()
ds2 = xr.open_dataset('data1_feb.nc',decode_times=False) #.load()
```

I choose random time from the data for ex. 50

```
fnu1 = ds1.isel(time=np.random.randint(0, ds1.time.size, n))
Now I want to extract similer random timesteps (50) from the second data file

fnu2 = ds2.isel(time=(dss.prec == ds1.time))
```

The error is :

```
ValueError: cannot reindex or align along dimension 'time' because the index has duplicate values
```

Comment: What does `dss.prec` stands for?  You want similar timesteps or exactly the same timesteps of 50?

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this helps:

```
new_ds1 = ds1.where(ds1['time'].isin(ds2['time']), drop=True)
new_ds2 = ds2.where(ds2['time'].isin(new_ds1['time']), drop=True)
```